# Why cortana works differently for keyboard and voice(Offline)

Tags: cortana

I've been playing around Cortana. I was looking for all the offline commands.

I've noticed something that cortana behaves differently for voice command and keyboard.

I said **'Open Internet Explorer'**. It opened internet explorer application.
But when I typed the same thing, It showed no internet connectivity is available.

And I tried with **'Show reminders'**. It worked for voice command. But did not worked while I tried in keyboard.

Again I tried with **'Cortana Settings'**. But this worked for both voice command and keyboard command.

While some commands works for both, some other works only for voice command.
I dont understand why would it work differently for voice command and keyboard command.

Comment: hm, using the dev preview every command you have described works for me in airplane mode. I set my region to US, not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: @Thomas mine is not dev preview version. My region is set as US too.

Answer (score -1):

This feature is not currently available but its hoped it will be soon included.
Whenever you type anything in Cortana search box than it performs a search from web and your phone.
It's expected that Cortana will have silent mode which allows us to make Cortana perform actions by typing.
This feature is expected to be released in Windows Phone 10 in March 2015!
:-)

Comment: Do you have any reference for that?